# jquery ui slider working odd on rotate

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, slider

I want to achieve the functionality of the `jquery ui slider` when `rotated 90 degrees`. I've tried rotating and then sliding up and down which is not working. But when clicked and dragged horizontally the slider is sliding vertically. Here is the fiddle which makes easy for you to understand.[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/Pm6uD/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating an element with css won't change it's functionality like that... It will just make it appear rotated, while the javascript still considers it a horizontal slider.

You can set a jQuery UI slider to be vertical by giving it the property `orientation: "vertical"`

See updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pm6uD/1/

Note that I also changed your `width` css to be `height`